# Set up Angular Application

Tags: angular, jboss, f5

We have Jboss servers and F5 url on which we already have a JSF/JAVA based web app already deployed and working.
We are trying to deploy a new Angular based application on the same servers using the same F5 url but with a different context root.

For this new application , when we hit the url we are not able to access the application.Is it that I cannot deploy two different types of app using same F5?

Comment: How is this jsf related?

Comment: There is no problem to host several applications behind the same domain name. If you are hosting your 2 applications on JBOSS you need to configure the contexts adequately, if you are running 2 servers (JBOSS + Angular) then I suppose they are listening on different ports and then you need either an LTM rule or an iRule to route traffic on their dedicated pool.

Answer (score -1):

Angular applications require environment configuration to run properly in production.

I recommend reviewing the deployment documentation provided by the Angular team:

https://angular.io/guide/deployment